# Read Display Order with diff from attributes when it will be i in base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes

I just tried one of the below approach to read Field Order from class based on that Attributes and make the Grid, it will be fine if we refer direct class.

I refer the below code :

```
public class ExportAttribute: Attribute
{
    public int FieldOrder { get; set; }

    public int FieldLength { get; set; }

    public ExportAttribute() { }

}
public class ExportClass
{
    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 2, FieldLength = 25 )]
    public dobule Salary{ get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder=1, FieldLength=25)]
    public string CompanyName{ get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 3, FieldLength = 3 )]
    public string CompanyAddress{ get; set; }

    public ExportClass() { }
}
```

Now I have base class with 2 more fields in base class , So I would like to inherit the base class for diff types of classes . Each class have the diff FieldOrder values

Eg:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 4, FieldLength = 25 )]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder=5, FieldLength=25)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 6, FieldLength = 3 )]
    public int Age { get; set; }

   }
```

When Export class is inherit the BaseClass order is fine  ,And Same base Class I have inherit in other class also But here base class order is diff . How Can we make FieldOrder is differentiate for each inherited classes .Can you please suggest any new approach for the same .

Thanks in Advance,
Venkat.

Comment: Put your common fields from the base class in the beginning? Or give your base fields a very high FieldOrder so they always appear at the end?

Comment: Hi , I got it your approach but here I have to maintain order for all fields including base and inherited class. Eg: For One of the Import Class LastName order is 4 and Same field in another Class Order is 2  like that it will be changed.